# Is it possible to store custom class object in Spark Data Frame as a column value?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, lsh

I am working on duplicate documents detection problem using LSH algorithm. To handle large-scale data, we are using spark.

I have around 300K documents with at least 100-200 words per document. On spark cluster, these are the steps we are performing on data frame.

1. Run Spark ML pipeline for converting text into tokens.

```
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([
        docAssembler,
        tokenizer,
        normalizer,
        stemmer,
        finisher,
        stopwordsRemover,
       # emptyRowsRemover
    ])
model = pipeline.fit(spark_df)
final_df = model.transform(spark_df)
```

2. For each document, get  MinHash  value using datasketch(https://github.com/ekzhu/datasketch/) library and store it as a new column.

```
final_df_limit.rdd.map(lambda x: (CalculateMinHash(x),)).toDF()
```

2nd step is failing as spark is not allowing us to store custom type value as a column.  Value is an object of class MinHash.

Does anyone know how can i store Minhash objects in dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it might be possible to save python objects in DataFrames, but you can circumvent this in a couple of ways:

- Store the result instead of the object (not sure about how MinHash works, but if the value is numerical/string, it should be easy to extract it from the class object).
- If that is not feasible because you still need some properties of the object, you might want to serialize it using [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), saving the serialized result as an encoded string. This forces you to de-serialize every time that you want to use the object.

  `final_df_limit.rdd.map(lambda x: base64.encodestring(pickle.dumps(CalculateMinHash(x),))).toDF()`
- An alternative might be to use the [Spark MinHash implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance) instead, but that might not suit all your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @martinarroyo. I resolved this using 1st option. I am getting Array of long value from minhash object and converting it into string.

Comment: Glad to hear that! It might be good if you could update your question with your final solution for completeness.