# Pyspark - create a new column with StructType using UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
df.withColumn("event", ..)
```

How to add a new column **event** to a dataframe which will be the result of `generate_header` ? How can we add a **Row** as the column value ?

May be we need to convert the function to UDF

```
def generate_header(df_row):
    
    header = {
        "id": 1,
        ...
    }

    return EntityEvent(header, df_row)


class EntityEvent:
    def __init__(self, _header, _payload):
        self.header = _header
        self.payload = _payload
```

Let's suppose we have something like this

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|book_id        |Author              |
+---------------+--------------------+
|865731         |{name: 'A',  }      |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

and we want to get this

```
+---------------+--------------------+------------------------------
|book_id        |Author              | event                        |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
|865731         |{name: 'A',  }      | {header: { id: '865731'}, payload: {name: 'A'}}
+---------------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am not sure how you want to use `EntityEvent` later, but is it possible to just have dictionary with `header` and `payload` in `event` column and you can convert it after you take out value from the dataframe?

Comment: yeah ! how can we create a `dict` (or struct) in the new column ?

Comment: Depends. if it is static, you can just use `create_map`, otherwise, you might need to combine  with other functions.  If you can show me what data exactly should be in `event` column, I can share code.  (data schema exactly but value can be fake)

Comment: @Emma you can check the updates

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create_map` to generate the MapType in column.

```py
(df.withColumn('event', F.create_map(
    F.lit('header'), F.create_map(F.lit('id'), F.col('book_id')),
    F.lit('payload'), F.col('Author'))
)
```

fyi: You probably cannot have Python object in Spark column.
[Is it possible to store custom class object in Spark Data Frame as a column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155341/is-it-possible-to-store-custom-class-object-in-spark-data-frame-as-a-column-valu)

**Update:**

If you need to derive a part that involves some Python library functions.

```py
import base64

# udf function takes the return type schema.
@F.udf(MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
def generate_header(book_id, author):
    b64str = base64.b64encode('some text'.encode('utf-8'))
    return {
        'header': { 'id': book_id, 'key': b64str },
        'payload': author
    }

df.withColumn('event', generate_header(F.col('book_id'), F.col('Author')))
```

Comment: Need to use the  `generate_header` function bcz there is some complex calculations

Comment: You can use UDF in that case, if the complex calculations requires low level calculations.  Otherwise, it is more efficient to use Spark functions.  I would be able  to suggest something if I know what type of calculation you are doing.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can use UDF, however, please consider checking my previous comment.

Comment: your 1st code doesn't really work, got the following error `due to data type mismatch: The given values of function map should all be the same type, but they are [map<string,string>, string]`

Comment: I mean the code of `create_map`

Comment: do you have exactly same schema as in question?

Comment: it seems that we can't include a constructed create_map object inside another one !

Comment: hmm, could be different spark version?  i can do that with Spark 3.0.1.  Make sure that you are closing the `create_map`, the child one before comma.

Comment: I'm using `pyspark= "==3.2.1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244781/discussion-between-emma-and-smaillns).